# Singelton behaviour with static libraries

Tags: c++, singleton, libraries

I made a test to check if singletons across shared libraries are really unique. The projects architecture looks like this

```
      +----------+main+-----------+
      |            +              |
      |            |              |
      v            v              v
   plugin     dynamicLib     staticLib
(dynamicLib)        ^             ^
      +             |             |
      |             |             |
      +-------------+-------------+
```

staticLib and dynamicLib have a singleton `instance` getter and function `func` which just prints instance adress and name. Plugin has a function `func` as well, which gets the singleton instances of the libraries and calls `func` on them. Finally main just calls all three `func`s. To my amazement the output is:

```
0x105bc20 Dynamic::func
0x105c050 Static::func
Now calling plugin...
Plugin: Calling libs ...
-------
0x105bc20 Dynamic::func
0x105c050 Static::func
-------
```

Okay singleton in dynamic libraries are obvious always unique, but why the heck is the static libraries instance unique too? I compiled this on linux with g++ (GCC) 6.1.1. Is this standard behaviour or different on win/osx?
Can you please explain why the static libs instance is unique and how this is possible. Afaik the symbol should be defined in both compilation units. Does the usage of the maiers singleton, which uses a local static in the getter, play a role?

The source:
http://www.filedropper.com/libtesttar

Comment: It's "singleton" (you hit it twice from five). And why do you even care? Singletons are masked global variables, so whenever you need singleton, you should think for a while about your architecture, because global variables are usually code smell. And with C++ there are always problems with static variables initialization order (vs libs init). But from your description it looks like you may have even multiple code copies linked for the same class. As C++ is not interpreted language, how can it even know the class from dynamic lib is the same one as in static lib? (I didn't check the source).

Comment: I want to implement a plugin system and want the ExtensionManager to be available to all plugins and the core. So I need a cross lib-boundary singleton. Is there a better way for this in c++?

Comment: So you want single global Extension manager. If it can be part of core, make it part of core? Then core has direct access to it. For plugins: you can give the instance of Extension manager to them during some required initialization step. If you don't want manager as part of core, load it from other dynamic lib, but use that one from core as well (so core will either be responsible for loading that dynamic lib, or it will actually receive the manager, just like plugins, from the code responsible for manager instantiation).

Comment: Actually I would give it to core as parameter too. Try to avoid static variables, they are total pain in unit testing. Params of init functions are "dependency injection", and will allow you to test the core/plugins with mock extension manager, when for whatever reason using real manager would be difficult/unwanted during particular test. Overall think about your architecture, which part is owning others, which is responsible about what, and finally don't hesitate to even have single global `Context *context;` allocated by app init, storing the instances of modules (ext_manager, core, ...).